# Two parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send two php values to a javascript function. Apparently it doesn't do anything. 
Is my syntax correct?

```
<script>
function onmouseclick(nr, name){
        alert(nr);
        alert(name);
    }
</script>

<?php
echo '<img onClick="javascript: onmouseclick('. $template->id .','. $template->name .');" "class="img" />';
?>
```

Comment: I encourage you to read the articles on quirksmode.org to learn about other (better) ways to bind event handlers. Then you can avoid all this string concatenation stuff: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. It would already help if you'd embed PHP into HTML/JS, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use as

```
echo '<img onClick="javascript: onmouseclick(\''. $template->id .'\',\''. $template->id .'\');" class="img" />';
```

Need to add the param inside quotes ' ' but since you are doing `echo '...'` you need to use escape \ so that the quotes are treated as string.

Answer (score 5):

You should add quotes:

```
echo '<img onClick="javascript: onmouseclick("'. $template->id .'", "'. $template->name .'");"
```

Comment: Not sure if this works but the browser will render the output as <img onClick="javascript: onmouseclick("aa", "bb"); /><script> here aa and bb are some values and so echo '<img onClick="javascript: onmouseclick(\''. $template->id .'\',\''. $template->id .'\');" class="img" />';
may solve ?

Comment: I use onClick="javascript: onmouseclick('.$template->id.','. $template->name .');" 

The syntaxis is correct. The problem is in the $template->name

Answer (score 0):

just use
without php tags

```
<img onClick="javascript:onmouseclick('<?php echo $template->id;?>','<?php echo $template->name;?>');" class="img" />
```

or with php tags

```
echo '<img onClick="javascript: onmouseclick("'. $template->id .'", "'. $template->name .'");"
```

Comment: This is a possibility but it's not what i want because i want to put the echo '<img.... in a while loop.

Comment: @Julian: You still don't need `echo` for that. In fact, you should avoid `echo`ing HTML as much as possible. It just makes your code harder to maintain in the long run. Here is an example with a `while` loop and without `echo`ing the HTML: http://codepad.org/B6Y0eeJZ. If you are using a fairly recent version of PHP, you can even use `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`, which makes the code even more readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for avoiding character escape

```
echo sprintf('<img onclick="%s" class="img"/>',sprintf("onmouseclick(%d,'%s');",$template->id,$template->id));
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.  This answer should have one `printf()`, no `echo` and no `sprintf()` calls.  If you are going to keep this answer here, please [edit] it to completely refactor the approach.